# Group, choice,all or sequence XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I have this type defined for the element "tag", tag can be an **image**,**quote** or **format**.

```
<complexType name="Tag">
        <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <element name="quote" type="rel:Quote" maxOccurs="1"
                minOccurs="0">
            </element>
            <element name="image" type="rel:Image" minOccurs="0"
                maxOccurs="1">
            </element>
            <element name="format" type="rel:Format" minOccurs="0"
                maxOccurs="1">
            </element>
        </choice>
</complexType>
```

How can I use for example

```
<rel:image></rel:image>
```

instead of

```
 <rel:tag><rel:image></rel:image></rel:tag>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML Schema has a construct of *substitition groups* which allows some elements substitute some other elements. This might be what you want.

For example, you may define an element `tag` of type `Tag`:

```
<xs:element name="tag" type="Tag"/>
```

And use it somewhere:

```
<xs:complexType name="Tags">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="tag"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Now you can define elements `quote`, `image` and `format` to be able to substitute `tag`:

```
<xs:element name="quote" type="Quote" substitutionGroup="tag"/>
<xs:element name="image" type="Image" substitutionGroup="tag"/>
<xs:element name="format" type="Format" substitutionGroup="tag"/>
```

`Quote`, `Image` and `Format` must be derived from the `Tag` type.

Now everywhere the `tag` element is used (per reference), it can be replaced by `quote`, `image` or `format` elements.

Geography Markup Language an example of a schema which uses this pattern, here's a link to somewhat outdated (but concise) version [2.1.2](http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/2.1.2/geometry.xsd).

The schema defines an abstract element `_Geometry`:

```
<element name="_Geometry" type="gml:AbstractGeometryType" abstract="true"/>

<complexType name="AbstractGeometryType" abstract="true">
    <annotation>
        <documentation>
    All geometry elements are derived from this abstract supertype; 
    a geometry element may have an identifying attribute (gid). 
    It may be associated with a spatial reference system.
  </documentation>
    </annotation>
    <complexContent>
        <restriction base="anyType">
            <attribute name="gid" type="ID" use="optional"/>
            <attribute name="srsName" type="anyURI" use="optional"/>
        </restriction>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

And then defines an element `Polygon` which can subsitute `_Geometry`:

```
<element name="Polygon" type="gml:PolygonType" substitutionGroup="gml:_Geometry"/>

<complexType name="PolygonType">
    <annotation>
        <documentation>
    A Polygon is defined by an outer boundary and zero or more inner 
    boundaries which are in turn defined by LinearRings.
  </documentation>
    </annotation>
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="gml:AbstractGeometryType">
            <sequence>
                <element ref="gml:outerBoundaryIs"/>
                <element ref="gml:innerBoundaryIs" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

So now you can use `Polygon` and other elements where `_Geometry` is referenced:

```
<complexType name="GeometryAssociationType">
    <annotation>
        <documentation>
    An instance of this type (e.g. a geometryMember) can either 
    enclose or point to a primitive geometry element. When serving 
    as a simple link that references a remote geometry instance, 
    the value of the gml:remoteSchema attribute can be used to 
    locate a schema fragment that constrains the target instance.
  </documentation>
    </annotation>
    <sequence minOccurs="0">
        <element ref="gml:_Geometry"/>
    </sequence>
    <attributeGroup ref="xlink:simpleAttrs"/>
    <attribute ref="gml:remoteSchema" use="optional"/>
    <!-- <attributeGroup ref="gml:AssociationAttributeGroup"/> -->
</complexType>
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Tag` is the type of element `tag`, then the way you have defined it, a `tag` element can contain a sequence of `quote`, `image`, or `format` children.

If you want `image` to be used in place of `tag`, then you should define the `image` element as a member of the substitution group with `tag` as its head.